# Particular integral of PDE.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The PDE $$\frac{\partial ^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}+2\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x\partial y}+\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial y^{2}}=x$$ Has

$1.$ Only one particular integral.

$2.$ a particular integral which is linear in x and .

$3.$a particular integral which is a quadratic polynomial is x and y.

$4.$ more than one particular integral.

I found  P.I. of the PDE as $\frac{x^{3}}{6}$ but its answer is given to be infinite particular integrals. Where i am wrong? Please suggest me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another particular solution you missed can be found as:
$\frac{1}{(D+D')^2}x=\frac{1}{D'^2}$$[1+\frac{D}{D'}]^{-2}x=\frac{1}{D'^2}(1-2D/D'+....]x=\frac{1}{D'^2}(x-2y)=\frac{xy^2}{2}-\frac{y^3}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to show that there is no unique solution to this PDE.

One of the simplest we can use to argue is: "the derivative doesn't read constants"

So if $u$ is a particoular integral of your PDE, then also $u+constant$ is

Comment: He found a particular solution, but reported that the right answer the book gave was that there were an infinite number of solution and he couldn't figure out why. Here's why

Comment: Okay, but consider elaborating a little, since you're answering rather than commenting. You've provided one possible case (adding a constant) which, of course, suffices to show that there are infinitely many solutions, but for this equation, a more general solution is possible, and your answer gives no indication of that at all. You might want to at least hint at such a possibility.

Comment: I see your point, I will be more careful, thank you!

Comment: General solution is $u=f(x-y)+xg(x-y)+\frac{x^3}{6}$. Then for any differentiable functions $f$ and $g$ this is also particular solution.